# How to include all boost header files?

Tags: java, c++, import, include, wildcard

In Java if you wanted all the classes in a namespace you could just do this:

```
import com.bobdylan.*;
```

Is there anyway I can get a result similar to:

```
import boost.*;
```

(except in C++)

Comment: I'd wonder how long it would take to compile a single file, if you included all of boost. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not automatically. You can write a single header file that #includes all the other headers you are interested in, and then just #include that, but that's it - C++ has no "import" feature like java.

Comment: * imports are not very popular anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to #include all of Boost -- it's a very large library, so just include what you need.

Also, a Neil says, there is no equivalent in C++ to the Java .* syntax, so you must either include them all manually, or write a single header that includes them all manually and include that.